# rewrite sub folder url query string

Tags: .htaccess

I am new to web development.

Below Htaccess code works fine in root directory files. While We try to rewrite the files in sub folder /test/downloadh.php. when i was changed below code will we can't get the root files links are notworking.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /test/
```

Would you please suggest us, how to get the url

http://example.com/test/downloadh/the-house-on-the-borderland

to

http://example.com/test/downloadh.php?id=the-house-on-the-borderland

Working Code:-

```
    # disable directory browsing
    Options -Indexes

    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
    FileETag MTime Size
    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

    # Turn mod_rewrite on
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+album\.php\?Id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ album/%1? [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^album/([^/]+)/?$ album.php?Id=$1 [L,QSA]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+download\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ download/%1? [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^download/([^/]+)/?$ download.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+downloada\.php\?linkb=([^\s&]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ downloada/%1? [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^downloada/([^/]+)/?$ downloada.php?linkb=$1 [L,QSA]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(?:downloadb\.php)?\?mlink=([^\s]+)&linkb=([^\s]+)? [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ downloadb/%1%2? [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^downloadb/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ downloadb.php?mlink=$1&linkb=$2 [L,QSA]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(?:songs\.php)?\?id=([^\s]+)&linkb=([^\s]+)? [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ songs/%1/%2? [R=301]
    RewriteRule ^songs/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ songs.php?id=$1&linkb=$2 [L,QSA]

    # CUSTOM ERRORPAGE
    ErrorDocument 401 /error/test.php
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/test.php
    ErrorDocument 404 /error/test.php
    ErrorDocument 500 /error/test.php
```

Error Code:-

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /downloadh(?:\.php)?\?id=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ downloadh/%1/? [R=302,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^downloadh/([^/]+)/?$ downloadh.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /test/downloadh.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^test/downloadh\.php /%1? [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^downloadh/([^/]+)/?$ /test/downloadh.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: do you want to redirect both /test/downloadh.php & /downloahd.php requests or only /test/downloadh.php ?

Comment: /test/downloadh.php url files Only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,7}\s/(test/downloadh)\.php\?id=(.+)\sHTTP.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^        %1/%2? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^test/downloadh/([^/]+)/?$ test/downloadh.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Fantastic. Really You Saved Me. Thank you once again for valuable Help.

Comment: I really appreciate the time you spent to help me. Thanks a lot and keep up the good work.

Comment: @vijaybharathi glad to help  and you are welcome , Thanks